# git: list of all changed files including those in submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-diff

I would like to get a list of all files, which have changed betweet two commits including those in submodules.

I know I can do this:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR ${revision} HEAD
```

It returns a list of files, including the submodule-path, but not the files within.

Example:
I've updated a submodule. I commited the super-project. Now I want to get a list of all files which have been modified.

Do you know a way to get this done?

Answer (score 58):

Update 2017: as I mentioned in "[see diff of commit on submodule in gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40895712/6309)",

- Git 2.11 (Nov. 2016) introduces

  ```
  git diff --submodule=diff
  ```
- Git 2.14 (Q3 2017) will improve that by recursing into nested submodules.
  See [commit 5a52214](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a5221427cb8b78c3246ffa305900db935017c54) (04 May 2017) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
  <sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a531ecf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a531ecf399a5d2ddb97dbd79bbcdad2dd93e7268), 29 May 2017)</sup>

---

Original 2012 answer (pre 2017 Git 2.14)

Maybe a simple line would be enough:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive git diff --name-status
```

That would actually list files in submodules *within* submodules.
(The `--recursive` option comes from git1.7.3+)

Comment: `git submodule update --remote --recursive` followed by your `foreach` `diff` command shows nothing (because it just runs `git diff` in each submodule). How can we see the diff of the update we just ran?

Comment: @Zaz an `update --remote` would change the gitlink (SHA1 representing the submodule commit checked out). If you can get the previous gitlink sha1 and the current one (with a simple `git diff` in the parent repo), you can then go in the submodule, and do a `git diff` between those two SHA1.

Comment: I thought the questioner was looking for a way to do that automatically.

Comment: I'm lookingfor the same as OP, the --submodule=diff works wonderfully, except in combination with --name-only. I need the files that changed, including the submodules. Is that somehow possible? git version is 2.17.1. Recursing doesn't work either, because I need to check against a specific merge-base on the top level repo.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Not sure: that would be a good question on its own.

Comment: @VonC OPs question is with name-only, I now used a workaround, I basically use your command, filter it with grep for the lines starting with +++ and --- and then cut the first part and pass that to uniq.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Got it. That seems not very convenient indeed.

Comment: This answer is incorrect as question is specific about --name-only which will not work.

Comment: @user64204 Agreed. That is what the previous comment from CodeMonkey alluded to.

Answer (score 5):

You can find out what version a submodule was at, as of a given parent module commit, using `git ls-tree`:

```
subcommit=$(git ls-tree $parentcommit $submodulepath | awk '{print $3}')
```

So here's a script that should get you much of the way there, up to output formatting and such:

```
#!/bin/sh

function compare {
    if [[ -z "$3" ]];
        then git diff --name-only --ignore-submodules=all --diff-filter=ACMR "$1" "$2"
        else git diff --name-only --ignore-submodules=all --diff-filter=ACMR "$1" "$2" | awk -v r=$3 '{ print "" r "/" $0}'
    fi

    for submodule in `git submodule | awk '{print $2}'`
    do
        old=$(git ls-tree $1 $submodule | awk '{print $3}')
        new=$(git ls-tree $2 $submodule | awk '{print $3}')
        (cd $submodule; compare $old $new $submodule)
    done
}

compare "$1" "$2"
```

This will output all files like this (although Base is a submodule):
HtmlTemplates/Css/Screen.css
Base/Php/Classes/Helper.php

Answer (score 3):

So, the very straightforward script that lists all changes compared to a revision

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Listing changes for super module"
git diff $1 --name-only
subs=(`git submodule | awk '{print $2}'`)
for sub in ${subs[*]}; do
   lastrevision=`git diff  $1 $sub | fgrep "Subproject" | head -n1 | awk '{print $3}'`
   cd $sub
   echo "Listing changes for $sub"
   git diff $lastrevision --name-only
   cd ..
done
```

it takes one argument - revision you want to compare with.
Make sure that there is `fgrep "Subproject"`, not `fgrep "Submodule"`.

Comment: Thank you. This will show me the files which have changed since the last commit of the submodules. But how do I get all files which have changed (including submodules) between to revisions of the super-project?

Comment: So you were committing submodules as well? I guess you will need some sort of a script...

Comment: ProTip™: Save this as `git-diff-submodules` and run it with `git diff-submodules`

Comment: @Zaz What is `git diff-submodules`?

Answer (score 3):

***July 8,2017***

Now to get a diff including that of a `submodule`, you can use the command -

```
git diff --submodule=diff
```

Note - This has been introduced with [Git 2.14.0](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.14.0.txt#L44)

> "git diff --submodule=diff" now recurses into nested submodules.

Comment: yes it does, but when I appliy --name-only it shows only submodule name, so i want changed files inside submod ... but not filecontent

Answer (score 2):

A Windows variant of https://stackoverflow.com/a/13169898/5438298 by [Jamey Sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1787206/jamey-sharp) would be

```
@echo off
if NOT %1.==. goto has_rev1

@echo git diff --name-only including submodules
@echo usage:
@echo ^ ^ %~n0 ^<revision1^> [^<revision2^>^|HEAD]
@exit /b 1

:has_rev1
setlocal
set rev1=%1
if %2.==. (set rev2=HEAD) else (set rev2=%2)

call :show_diff %rev1% %rev2%
exit /b
::eof

:show_diff
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=*" %%l in ('git --no-pager diff --name-only --ignore-submodules^=all --line-prefix^=%3 %1 %2') do set fwds=%%l & set bcks=!fwds:/=\! & echo !bcks! 
endlocal
::git submodule is too slow for this
::for /f "tokens=2" %%d in ('git submodule') do call :subm %1 %2 %%d %3
if exist .gitmodules for /f "tokens=1,3*" %%p in (.gitmodules) do if %%p.==path. call :subm %1 %2 %%q %3
exit /b
::show_diff

:subm
setlocal
for /f "tokens=3" %%r in ('git ls-tree %1 %3') do set rev1=%%r
for /f "tokens=3" %%r in ('git ls-tree %2 %3') do set rev2=%%r

set fwdslash=%3
set bckslash=%fwdslash:/=\%

pushd %bckslash%
call :show_diff %rev1% %rev2% %4%bckslash%\
popd

endlocal
exit /b
::subm
```

(note that it might need a few more double quotes for spaces in the submodule names to work).

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised nobody has said this, but as of v1.8.1 you can do this:

```
git config diff.submodule diff
```

and now all `git diff` commands for two revs will also diff the contents (not just the refs) of submodules.

Answer (score 0):

I use now with git 2.32.0:

git diff --submodule=diff

and parse output with regular expression pattern: "--- a/(.*)"

Comment: Will not work with "Renamed"

Comment: thx for the hint.

Comment: will not work for newly added files either

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
git -c color.diff=false diff --submodule=diff HEAD~1 HEAD | sed -n -e s/^diff\ --git\ a\\///p
```

to just have a list of your files (with HEAD~1 and HEAD as example refs).

I prefer

```
git -c color.diff=false diff --submodule=diff HEAD~1 HEAD | grep -E "^(diff|Submodule)\ "
```

to group the files by submodules. Depending on the terminal, it can be important to use the "--no-pager" option, as shown in the following remark.

Remark: I like the complete colored diffs in a file, which can be "htmlized" for presentation afterwards:

```
git -c color.diff=always --no-pager diff --submodule=diff HEAD~1 HEAD > diffFileName
```