# How can I get a list of all modified files for submodules with git?

Tags: git, git-submodules, githooks, git-log

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [git: list of all changed files including those in submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757091/git-list-of-all-changed-files-including-those-in-submodules)

I have a super repository that has many submodules that are regularly being updated. I have a post-receive hook setup for this super repository that does maintenance after every commit.

I'm trying to get a list of all modified files in a commit, which includes any files that have been modified after a submodule has been updated.

Here's how I do it for a repo without submodules:

`git show --pretty="format:" --name-only HEAD | tr '\n' ' '`

...which will output something like `testing1.html testing2.html foo.md bar.js`, which is the desired format (space-delimited filenames).

My question is, how can I get a list of *all* the modified files for a single commit, including the files that have changed in submodules?