# Generate patch of uncommitted changes for git repo and submodules

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

I have a git repo `foo` that has several submodules in their own folders `bar` and `baz` (the actual repo is eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator). I need to generate patches for changes to those repos.

I can generate a patch with `git --no-pager diff > file.patch` which is fine for changes to `foo` but doesn't report changes in the `bar` or `baz`, the submodules.

Using `git submodule --quiet foreach --recursive git --no-pager diff > file` (cribbed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13100667/1554850)) nearly works but the diffs don't include the names of the folders the subrepos live in.

Presently I work round this by hacking the paths into the patches by hand but that only works for simple patches and the scripting solutions I can think of (e.g. getting the subrepo names from git, changing to the folders, generating the patches in folders) mean I can't use a simple `git apply` to reapply the patches later.

Is there a way to get git to diff the subrepos directly rather than through foreach so the generated patches can be simply applied?

Comment: Take a look at `git diff --help`, in particular the `--src-prefix` and `--dist-prefix` options, which may help out.

Comment: @larsks Yes! that was the clue that I needed. With those options I can splice the repo folder into the patch which gives me the result I need. However, note the proviso in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the clue offered by @larsks I managed to find the following one liner which does what I need:

```
git submodule --quiet foreach --recursive 'export NAME="${PWD##*/}"; git --no-pager diff --src-prefix="a/${NAME}/" --dst-prefix="b/${NAME}/"'
```

This adds the folder name of the subfolders into the patch generated with `git diff` so I can just run `git apply` in the parent folder even if the patch spans more than one of the submodules. Note however that it only works because my submodules are all one folder below the main repo folder. That could be overcome if needed by changing the code used to set `NAME` to something a little more clever.

Comment: git sets some variables you can use instead of $PWD. Also, `$path` works for submodule directories that are not in the repository root: `git diff --src-prefix="a/$path/" --dst-prefix="b/$path/"`

Answer (score 3):

In source repository run

- to **generate** patch file **without nested submodules** (include only top level modules):

```bash
(git --no-pager diff --src-prefix= --dst-prefix=;\
  git submodule foreach --quiet 'git --no-pager diff --src-prefix=$sm_path/ --dst-prefix=$sm_path/' \
) > uncommited.patch
```

- to **generate** patch file **with nested submodules**:

```bash
(git --no-pager diff --src-prefix= --dst-prefix=;\
 GIT_PROJECT_PATH=$PWD git submodule foreach --quiet --recursive 'git --no-pager diff --src-prefix=$(realpath --relative-to=$GIT_PROJECT_PATH $PWD)/ --dst-prefix=$(realpath --relative-to=$GIT_PROJECT_PATH $PWD)/' \
) > uncommited.patch
```

In destination repository run to **apply** patch:

```bash
git apply -p 0 uncommited.patch
```

###### Description

- `--no-pager` prevents `diff` interactive mode (notice it is `git` parameter, not `diff`).
- `--src-prefix=` and `--dst-prefix=` (empty value; `;` is command separator, not value) remove default path prefix, so they contain only relative values.
- `--quiet` prevents lines starting with *Entering* for each folder to appear in patch file.
- `--recursive` dives into nested submodules.
- `realpath` generates relative path to source root.
- `$sm_path` is environment variable provided by `git submodule foreach` containing relative module folder path.
- `$PWD` (when used in `foreach`) is environment variable with current module folder absolute path.
- `GIT_PROJECT_PATH` is arbitrary named environment variable with source root absolute path (exists only during command execution). When modules are not nested, `foreach` provides `$toplevel` variable with same value.
- `uncommited.patch` is file with diff for source root and all submodules with paths relative to source root.
- `-p 0` treats paths as relative to source root when applying (disables leading slashes stripping in paths).

Answer (score 0):

With submodules the idea is that each repo is independent, it may be supported by different maintainers and have different process of approvals. Moreover, the repos could be checked out separately and even be part of completely different repo as submodule.

So, the approach here is to create patch-sets independently for each repo and pass them through independently. It makes more sense if you create patches after commits with `git format-patch`.