# see diff of commit on submodule in gitlab

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a gitlab version 7.3 that is working totally fine when I work with normal repositories.
However, I added a github submodule inside my gitlab project.
On my repo, I did after commit and push ( git push --recurse-submodules=check ) and it worked perfectly.

But now, I can see my commit on gitlab, but the diff isnt displayed when I browse it on my gitlab with chrome.
All the commits on files outside the submodules are well displayed meanwhile.
Is that a known issue?

Do I have something to do another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue... about Git itself.

It was resolved today with Git 2.11 and its new `git diff --submodule=diff`:

[image]
<sup>(picture from "[What is new in Git 2.11](https://hackernoon.com/whats-new-in-git-2-11-64860aea6c4f#.3dpv8bvwj)" from [Tim Pettersen](https://twitter.com/kannonboy))</sup>

This is not available through GitLab GUI, since it just got released in Git.

---

Note: only Git 2.13 (Q2 2017) fixes a bug in that feature:

See [commit 17b254c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17b254cda6dd77b1a91ac6f2946943e52698efa9) (31 Mar 2017) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1776a71](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1776a710d615c77e3c66be2f4a08c36663f88a07), 17 Apr 2017)</sup>

> Running `git diff --submodule=diff` in a submodule which has it's own submodules that have changes get the error:
>
> ```
> fatal: bad object.
> ```
>
> This happens, because we do not properly initialize the environment
> in which the diff is run in the submodule.
> That means we inherit the environment from the main process, which sets environment variables. (Apparently we do set environment variables which we do not set when not in a submodules, i.e. the `.git` directory is linked)

---

Note: Git 2.14 still improve that command "`git diff --submodule=diff`", which now recurses into nested submodules.

See [commit 5a52214](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a5221427cb8b78c3246ffa305900db935017c54) (04 May 2017) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a531ecf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a531ecf399a5d2ddb97dbd79bbcdad2dd93e7268), 29 May 2017)</sup>

> ### `diff`: recurse into nested submodules for inline diff

> When [fd47ae6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd47ae6a5b9cc0cfc56c1f7c43db612d26ca4b75) (`diff`: teach `diff` to display submodule difference with an inline diff, 2016-08-31, Git 2.11) was introduced, we did not think of recursing into nested submodules.
>
> When showing the inline diff for submodules, automatically recurse
> into nested submodules as well with inline submodule diffs.

---

Before Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), "[`git diff --submodule=diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/75405e72703e2205eac2585e0c09a3e9751720f2/Documentation/git-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> showed failure from `run_command()` when trying to run diff inside a submodule, when the user manually removes the submodule directory.

That has been fixed.

See [commit 67f61ef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67f61efbb92dce64b33c3280b89e9f253a34df1c), [commit f1c0368](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1c0368da4d64f394e4c099cb3c232671040d725) (31 Aug 2021), and [commit 4577d26](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4577d26dc0aaae3bb35c8906db96ba043716f3f7) (26 Jul 2021) by [David Turner (`csusbdt`)](https://github.com/csusbdt).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 75405e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75405e72703e2205eac2585e0c09a3e9751720f2), 20 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`diff --submodule=diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67f61efbb92dce64b33c3280b89e9f253a34df1c): don't print failure message twice
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: David Turner</sup>

> When we fail to start a diff command inside a submodule, immediately exit the routine rather than trying to finish the command and printing a second message.

Comment: I wasnt expecting eaching the limits of git so early! 
Do you think when it will be implemented on gitlab it will be retroactive and I will see properly my diffs one day in gitlab?  (i don't expect a formal yes knowing that you won't personally implement this, but just by experience I want your opinion) 
Thanks for the information, I will forgot using the GUI of gitlab for a while until it is updated then.

Comment: @NicolasD the best course of action is to log an issue on the GitLab project requesting for integrating that new Git feature.

Comment: it is done in this issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/25213. 
I will keep this SO question updated when the issue is solved.