# Git diff doesn't work within submodule

Tags: windows, git, diff, git-diff, winmerge

I'm on Windows 10, using Git command line and have WinMerge set up as my difftool.

I have a repository with several submodules. When running "git diff" and "git difftool" within the main repo, it correctly uses WinMerge to analyze the files. When I navigate to a submodule and run "git diff" or "git difftool" it does nothing.

Here's my .gitconfig:

```
[diff]
    tool = winmerge
[difftool "winmerge"]
    cmd = winmergeu -e \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

This is what I get when I git diff in the parent repo:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/content/themes/baseline-theme b/content/themes/baseline-theme
--- a/content/themes/baseline-theme
+++ b/content/themes/baseline-theme
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 30901f86ba56be092f1ed5c7095204abe7f64b27
+Subproject commit 30901f86ba56be092f1ed5c7095204abe7f64b27-dirty
```

I get no output when I run the same command in the submodule.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Submodules are evil. See [Mastering Git submodules](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-submodules-34c65e940407)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need at least Git 2.11 for `git diff --submodule=diff` to work.

And 2.14 for it to work in submodules of submodules (ie recursively).
See my answer "[see diff of commit on submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40895712/6309)".

Comment: This is good, and it essentially does what I'm asking for. It still has two medium-sized issues: it doesn't work for git difftool, and in my Git Bash (Windows) it screws up the terminal so that all text entered is not visible. But thank you.

Comment: @develdevil Strange: what version of Git are you using? Is your Git bash using at least Lucida font?

Comment: @develdevil Note: `git difftool` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool) accepts the same options as `git diff`. So this should work with `git difftool` too.

Comment: git version 2.14.1.windows.1 -
I realized the issue with the prompt was partially user error. I was using Ctrl-C to escape from vim instead of q. And when I run git difftool --submodule=diff it opens the submodule reference file in WinMerge instead of the changed files within the submodule.

Comment: Update: Seems like everything is working these days when I run git difftool from within the subdirectory. Maybe all it needed was a reboot.